# Select pickle file to plot in Voila

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, voila

I'm creating some plots in python and save them with pickle. Now I want to have a dropdown in Voila to select the file and to plot it. But I can't find a way to update the plot. Creating the dropdown with the files and observe the change is not the problem. This is my example code:

```
with open('plots/20211202.obj', 'rb') as file:
   fig = pickle.load(file)

def update():
   with open('plots/20211203.obj', 'rb') as file:
       fig = pickle.load(file)   
   fig.canvas.draw()
   fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

With this example it should just change the xxx2.obj file to xxx3.obj file but it doesn't change anything in the plot. What am I missing here?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I've had success using ipywidgets interact to handle this. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/pause-appmode-to-wait-for-user-input/12094/2?u=fomightez) and the example in the other discussion I link to for some ideas you can hopefully adapt. Just ignore the appmode discussion.

Comment: Hello Wayne, thank you so much for this link of your examples, this was exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks again and best regards!