# File Upload Widget with Voila Library (ipywidgets)

Tags: file-upload, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets, voila

I'm trying to create a jupyter notebook web app using Voila whereby users can upload a JSON file, and then based upon that JSON file a dashboard will be created. I am trying to do this by using the File Upload widget in ipywidgets.

In Voila, it will not run the subsequent cells once you open up the HTML website it creates for you so I am having a lot of trouble trying to get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Voila doesn't work that way IIUC. It basically needs to run all the code of each cell before generating the Voila interface & so if it gets to one where you want interaction, it will only expose the first ones & then that one in the Voila interface. At least that is what I think you are describing being your issue?   However, it allows making interactive interfaces that can be observed and trigger other events. So the way around this is to get to your cell where you do the file upload,& then trigger making a link to the your dashboard or change the current view to include your dashboard.

Comment: See [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70889215/8508004) for a link to a semi-related post that links to another one. The Voila resources in there should provide you with some guidance. (Or maybe appmode is closer to what you want?) Also have you looked for examples closer to what you hope to do at the [Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/)? Also I found [this Voila example](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/dpgoldenberg/be5a5819667834d8d98cf19f2e7bb45a/HEAD?urlpath=%2Fvoila%2Frender%2Fexp2_sim.ipynb) impressive.

Comment: I found another library that is far superior to Voila for what I wanted to do called Streamlit. But I have seen a lot of other people fall into this problem as well. Thank you for your response.