# ipywidgets FileUpload does not work when using Voila

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, voila

I'm trying to upload an image through the ipywidget FileUpload widget:

```
btn_upload = widgets.FileUpload()
```

To be able to run inside a notebook, I had to adjust websocket_max_message_size, otherwise, the notebook hangs, as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946897/file-upload-widget-with-voila-library-ipywidgets).

I could do that using classical jupyter server using a customized jupyter_notebook_config.py

```bash
jupyter notebook --config="/path/to/user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py" bear_classifier.ipynb
```

```
...
c.ServerApp.tornado_settings = {"websocket_max_message_size": 100 * 1024 * 1024}
...
```

When running the notebook, I'm unable to adjust this websockect_max_message_size, so the execution hangs after selecting a file.

I already tried setting config through command line options

```bash
voila bear_classifier.ipynb --Voila.tornado_settings="{'websocket_max_message_size': 209715200}"
```

Or even through a custom app

```py
from voila.app import Voila, _, Dict

class CustomVoila(Voila):
  tornado_settings = Dict(
    {
      'websocket_max_message_size': 209715200
    },
    config=True,
    help=_(
        "Extra settings to apply to tornado application, e.g. headers, ssl, etc"
    ),
  )

app = CustomVoila()
```

Do you have any idea what else could I try?